# Return all arrays that meet property condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, return

I am trying to return all arrays that meet a condition which is
property `gmarker[i].pricefirsthour` equal to 2. How can I achieve that? This below is just sample:

```
for (var i = 0; i < gmarker.length; i++) {
    if (gmarker[i].pricefirsthour = 2) {
        console.log("is equal to 2");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gmarker[i].pricefirsthour = 2` is not a condition, but an assignment that evaluates to `2` (and is thus always truthy). You need `==` or `===`, not `=`.

Alternately, shorter, with newer JS features:

```
gmarker.filter(x => x.pricefirsthour === 2)
```

Comment: @Rockafella—be careful with arrow functions, they were introduced with ECMAScript 2015 and may not be supported by all browsers that you care about (such as any version if IE), see [*MDN support matrix*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
gmarker = gmarker.filter(function(o){
   return o.pricefirsthour == 2;
});
```

```js
var gmarker = [{pricefirsthour:2},{pricefirsthour:21},{pricefirsthour:2},{pricefirsthour:7},{pricefirsthour:5},{pricefirsthour:2}];
gmarker = gmarker.filter(function(o){
   return o.pricefirsthour == 2;
});
console.log(gmarker);
```